# ckeditor - adding more editors to textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Im trying to add some editors to the textareas

When i write

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor5"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor6"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor7"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor8"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor9"></textarea>
```

It works just as i want.. But im using this to add more textbo

```
message = new Array();
jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
    $("#articles_textarea").html('');
    for (i=0;i<test;++i) { 
        if (message[i]) { $("#articles_textarea").append('<h2>askda</h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + [i] + '"></textarea>'); }
        else { message[i] = ''; $("#articles_textarea").append('<h2>askda</h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + [i] + '"></textarea>'); }
    }
}
```

And in the beginning it only ads 1 textarea and then the ck editor works.. But if i add more of these it won't work..

Hopefully you people got an answer like always!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BpvQ5/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle for that? then it will be easy for us

Comment: Sure thing! I can fix that :)

Comment: Fiddle in edit! But now i noticed that it didn't work at all with my script :S

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, and it works http://jsfiddle.net/BpvQ5/3/ but I'm not familiar with the ckeditor script that you are using.  Technically the code is working, and the textareas are generating, it's just not picking up that they need to be formatted as cheditor.

Comment: It only worked when i had $("#articles_textarea").update_textarea(1) not with the loop, it shuts down totally.. :/


This fiddle is only with the loop and it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/BpvQ5/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create dinamically a new textarea, need to call `CKEDITOR.replace` to replace this textarea as an editor:

```
jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) 
{ 
    $("#articles_textarea").html('');
    for (i=0;i<test;++i) 
    {       
        if (message[i]) 
            { 
                $("#articles_textarea").append('<h2>askda</h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + i + '"></textarea>'); 
            }else {
                message[i] = ''; $("#articles_textarea").append('<h2>askda</h2><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor' + i + '"></textarea>'); 
            }
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' + i );
    }
}
```

Anyway, your code fails because you are creating new textareas with the id of the olders.

http://jsfiddle.net/BpvQ5/4/